# Style div display table-row can be styled or not

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS table using divs only, I need to set style to the div ROW like this:

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:80px">
<div style="display:table-row;width:100%;height:80px; background:#333">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;height:auto"> 1 </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:auto; height:auto"> 2 </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;height:auto"> 3 </div>
</div>

more rows and tds in CSS
</div>
```

Questions:

1.- because div display table is set to 80px height will divs display table-cell respect and follow the width and height using those width:auto and height:auto ?

2.- Can divs display:table-row be styled with background width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes to both of your questions, in fact there is lot more you can do with `display:table` using CSS styling

CSS has properties to make any element you wish behave as if it was a table element. You'll need to structure them essentially as you would a table, and it will be subject to the same source-order-dependency as a table, but you can do it. I'm not crapping on it either, it's genuinely useful sometimes. If that layout style solves a problem and has no negative order implications, use it.

Don't use inline styles, but just for understanding here's how that would go:

```
<section style="display: table;">
  <header style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </header>
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
display: table                /* <table>     */
display: table-cell           /* <td>        */
display: table-row            /* <tr>        */
display: table-column         /* <col>       */
display: table-column-group   /* <colgroup>  */
display: table-footer-group   /* <tfoot>     */
display: table-header-group   /* <thead>     */
```

Comment: Thanks amigo. Just a small question: To use those divs because it is a 3 column template does I need to set float:left and none and right when using this kind of css tables or not?

Comment: making table structure don't need to float table-cell level element.